Uploading a picture in react using multer
I have two files, the server file and  My register file. So on the server side, I have the following code for the server file
import multer from 'multer';

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file, cb) {
        return cb(null, "public/images")
    },
    filename: function(req, file, cb) {
        return cb(null, `${Date.now()}_${file.originalname}`)
    }
})
const upload = multer({storage:storage})

app.post('/register', upload.single('user_profilepic'), (req, res) => {
    const sql = "INSERT INTO users (`user_firstname`, `user_lastname`, `user_username`, `user_gender`, `user_location`, `user_phone_no`, `user_email`, `user_password`, `user_category`, `user_profilepic`, `user_skill`) VALUES (?)";
     {
        if (err) return res.json({Error: "Password hashing error!"})
        const values = [
            req.body.user_firstname,
            req.body.user_lastname,
            req.body.user_username,
            req.body.user_gender,
            req.body.user_location,
            req.body.user_phone_no,
            req.body.user_email,
            req.body.user_category,
            req.file.filename,
            req.body.user_skill
        ]

        db.query(sql, [values], (err, result) => {
            console.log(req.file.filename)
            if (err) return res.json({Error: "Values Entry Error!"});
            return res.json({Status: "Data Entry Successful"})
        })
    })
});


and this is the code for the register file
import axios from 'axios';

function Register() {

    const [values, setValues] = useState({
        user_firstname: '',
        user_lastname: '',
        user_username: '',
        user_gender: '',
        user_location: '',
        user_phone_no: '',
        user_email: '',
        user_category: '',
        user_profilepic: {},
        user_skill: ''
    })

    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        axios.post('http://localhost:5500/register', values)
        .then(res => {
            if (res.data.Status === 'Data Entry Successful') {
                alert("Sign Up Successful!");
                navigate('/login');
            }
            else {
                alert(res.data.Error);
            }
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }

<input type='file' name='image' required='required' placeholder='Select Image' onChange={(e) => setValues({...values, user_profilepic: e.target.files[0]})} />

The code works but I am not seeing anything being uploaded to the destination folder in the server and also in the MySQL database. Am not getting an error at all, both from the frontend side and the backend side. Both say that they have compiled successfully. Please help
I was expecting the image to be saved on the localdisk and the file name/path to be saved on the MySQL. Then after being called, the image can be displayed on the frontend with other data

You need to sent data as FormData and set content-type to multipart/form-data.
const handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();
    Object.entries(values).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        formData.set(key, value);
    });
    axios
        .post('http://localhost:5500/register', formData, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            }
        })
        .then(res => {
            if (res.data.Status === 'Data Entry Successful') {
                alert('Sign Up Successful!');
                navigate('/login');
            } else {
                alert(res.data.Error);
            }
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
};


Now if I am to display the image to the frontend img src tag, what would I use?

you will need to serve the public/images folder as express static app.use(express.static('public/images')) and store the path or name of the image in db. For ex, image name would be profile.jpg then you will need to build the URL from http://localhost:5500/public/images as base URL, finally output is http://localhost:5500/public/images/profile.jpg

Your method helps alot. The only difficult part was that I was using different pictures for different people and I was wondering if I would be able to assign the images to the respectful account. I came up with this instead through your help: <img src={http://localhost:5500/images/ + data.user_profilepic} alt='Profile Pic' /> Thanks alot Mr Yuvaraj

happy coding :)

does the web server and the backend server sharing the same scheme, host and port? if not there will be a cors problem, you can create a proxy server in web server to fix it.

No... They are on different port numbers

it may be a cors problem, and you can use proxy table (if after realse they will be same), or nginx forwarding. In short, the goal is to post requests without cross-domain

I tried what you said but I discovered that there were two conflicting statements of multer.. When I removed the second one, am getting an error on the server side and there is no image being attached to the destination folder

This should be a comment and not an answer
